# not nillable yet required and null value

Tags: jaxb

I just found a curious case of JAXB with my colleague.

I declared a field with `@XmlElement(required = true)` which is `nillable = false` as default.

But I, by accident, tried to marshall an instance with the value of null.

And I saw that the element is just omitted. Is it normal? Is it just a programmer's fault?

```java
import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlRootElement
public class Doughan {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws JAXBException, IOException {

        final JAXBContext context =
            JAXBContext.newInstance(Doughan.class);

        final Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);

        System.out.println("\n------------------------------------- not valid, is it?");
        marshaller.marshal(new Doughan(), System.out);

        System.out.println("\n------------------------------------------------- valid");
        marshaller.marshal(new Doughan("Blaise"), System.out);

        System.out.println("\n------------------------------------------------ schema");
        context.generateSchema(new SchemaOutputResolver(){
                @Override public Result createOutput(final String namespaceUri,
                                                     final String suggestedFileName)
                    throws IOException {
                    return new StreamResult(System.out) {
                        @Override public String getSystemId() {
                            return "Do I really have to do this?";
                        }
                    };
                }
            });
    }

    public Doughan() {
        this(null);
    }

    public Doughan(final String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    @XmlElement(required = true) // default; nillable = false
    private String name;

    @XmlElement(nillable = true, required = true)
    private String nill = null;
}
```

Here comes what I got.

```xml
------------------------------------- not valid, is it?
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<doughan>
    <nill xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
</doughan>

-------------------------------------- valid, isn't it?
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<doughan>
    <name>Blaise</name>
    <nill xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
</doughan>

------------------------------------------------ schema
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="doughan" type="doughan"/>
  <xs:complexType name="doughan">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="nill" type="xs:string" nillable="true"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

xmllint

```
$ head -n100 doughan.xsd doughan1.xml doughan2.xml
==> doughan.xsd <==
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="doughan" type="doughan"/>
  <xs:complexType name="doughan">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="nill" type="xs:string" nillable="true"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
==> doughan1.xml <==
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<doughan>
    <nill xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
</doughan>
==> doughan2.xml <==
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<doughan>
    <name>Blaise</name>
    <nill xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
</doughan>

$ xmllint --schema doughan.xsd doughan1.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<doughan>
    <nill xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
</doughan>
Element 'nill': This element is not expected. Expected is ( name ).
doughan1.xml fails to validate

$ xmllint --schema doughan.xsd doughan2.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<doughan>
    <name>Blaise</name>
    <nill xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
</doughan>
doughan2.xml validates

$
```

With respects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if an element is not annotated with `@XmlElement(nillable=true)` then null values will be omitted from the XML document.

**For More Informatation**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/04/binding-to-json-xml-handling-null.html

**Note:**  I'm guessing that you were targetting me with that question :).

Comment: Thank your for your answer. So an element which has `nillable=false` yet `required=true` can be omitted if the value is `null` which leads the **document invalid against schema**? Could it be more convenient if a Marshaller complains for us? Merry Christmas, anyway.

Comment: @JinKwon - You can always set an instance of `Schema` on the `Marshaller` to have JAXB complain when an invalid document is being marshalled:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-marshalunmarshal-schema.html